# How to create new variable from two existing categorical variables in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have two different category variables: `A=factor(c(1,2,1,2,1))` and `B=factor(c("g","g","h","g","h"))`. I want to have a new categorical variable based on these two categories. For example I want to call `(1,g)=K, (2,g)=J, (1,h)=L`. So the new variable will be `factor(c("K","J","L","J","L"))`.

Comment: Well, you can concatenate the two factor variables as follow: `as.factor(paste0(as.character(A),as.character(B)))`, but you still need to know which category correspond to your new category K, J, L... so I don't really understand what you are looking for here.

Comment: Perhaps: `factor(paste0(A, B), labels = c("K", "J", "L"))`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a named vector to achieve this:

```
A <- factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1))
B <- factor(c("g", "g", "h", "g", "h"))

conv <- c("1 g" = "K",
          "2 g" = "J",
          "1 h" = "L")

C <- conv[paste(A, B)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$Cross_Tab <- dplyr::case_when(
  df$A %in% c ("1") & 
    df$B %in% c ("g") ~ K,
  df$A %in% c ("2") & 
    df$B %in% c ("g") ~ J,
  df$A %in% c ("1") & 
    df$B %in% c ("h") ~ L,
  )
```

Comment: Thanks @Shree, for the edit. I am new here, could not figure out the formatting

Comment: No problem.  [How to format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: + Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.